# Video streaming, How it works?

Tags: networking, video-streaming, streaming

As i starting to work with video streaming, i've got a question:
Video streaming is the process of breaking video file into small data packages that are sent over network. But where do they stored and what happen with it after streaming was finished? I am asking because unlike from download, streaming does not keep the file locally, that's how it described in internet. What is the process of handling stream buffers under the hood. Can someone point me into right direction?

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most video streams are actually HTTP request and response based - i.e. he client (player) request the video chunk by chunk and then plays it as it receives each chunk.

To answer your question what happens to the chunks when they are downloaded, this will depend on the player and the device. In general the chunks will be rebuilt into the particular video container that is being used, e.g. mp4, and then played.

How long they are stored will depend on the device and the players caching rules and capacity.